# SQLite database returning the same value for two different columns

Tags: android, database, sqlite

I have a SQLite database file which comes from external system. I am programming an Android app which uses this database. Database is opened/written to fine and is usable (I was a bit worried about version conflicts), but at one point in code when querying database with `SQLiteCursor` it erroneously returns the same value for two different fields (`ID_ATRAS_VIETA`, `DESCRIPTION_ATRAS_VIETA`), which is equal with first field's value. Values are **NOT** equal, I have checked and double-checked many times and with various DB software. What's going on?
 Database can be downloaded here: https://www.dropbox.com/s/7up38o5ddgnqa4d/PMLInventMobile_base.db3?dl=0

Code:

```
public PamatlidzekliInventarsDBEntry getAssetById(int ID) throws InvalidFormatException {
        SQLiteDatabase db = mDBOpenHelper.getReadableDatabase();

String cols[] = {"ID","NUMURS","NOSAUK","TIPS","SCANNED","SCANNED_TIME","SCANNED_DESCRIPTION_USER","SCANNED_ID_USER","SCAN_TYPE",
        "JAUNS","ID_ATRAS_VIETA","DESCRIPTION_ATRAS_VIETA","ATRAS_VIETA_CHANGED","NEW_ID_ATRAS_VIETA","NEW_DESCRIPTION_ATRAS_VIETA",
        "ID_MAT_ATBILD","DESCRIPTION_MAT_ATBILD","MAT_ATBILD_CHANGED","NEW_ID_MAT_ATBILD","NEW_DESCRIPTION_MAT_ATBILD","ID_LIETOTAJS",
        "DESCRIPTION_LIETOTAJS","LIETOTAJS_CHANGED","NEW_ID_LIETOTAJS","NEW_DESCRIPTION_LIETOTAJS","KOMENTARI","LEMUMS"};

        String args[] = {String.valueOf(ID)};

        Cursor c  = db.query("PamatlidzekliInventars",cols,"ID=?", args, null, null, null);

        if (c.moveToFirst()) {
            Integer atrasVietaId = c.isNull(c.getColumnIndexOrThrow("ID_ATRAS_VIETA")) ? null : c.getInt(c.getColumnIndexOrThrow("ID_ATRAS_VIETA"));  //returns 1068
            String atrasVietaDescription = c.getString(c.getColumnIndexOrThrow("DESCRIPTION_ATRAS_VIETA"));  //also returns '1068' but is equal to something else!!!
```

Comment: While try to open in nline db browse Error: Database disk image is malformed.(sqliteoneline.com) what software you using it to open ?